# I need URLs typed into Google Sheet cells to open automatically when they are finished being typed

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, automatic-updates

I have a QR code scanner setup that is linked to a google form that when the qr code is scanned, it automatically inputs a selection on the google form. It works well but every time you scan one QR code in the search bar, you would have to open up another tab or select a new search bar in order to input another selection. I am trying to automate this that way when you scan a QR code, it types the url into a cell on google sheets and then after it is done typing, google sheets automatically opens that url into a new tab.

Dont know where to start and could use some help!